# Resize widget in Experience Builder

Tags: widget, arcgis-experience-builder

I'm developing a custom widget in experience builder. I need to increase the height of the widget. I tried to adjust the `deafaultSize` in  `Manifest.json`, but it is not reflecting the widget size.

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultSize` in `Manifext.json` will only set the **initial** size the widget will be when added into an app. That is, when you first add the widget in Experience Builder. Once it is added, any changes to that value in the manifest will not override the layout within the Experience.

More information on the properties in `Manifest.json` can be found [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/experience-builder/api-reference/jimu-core/WidgetManifest)